# The specified module could not be found. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8007007E while trying to show table data in visual studio

Tags: visual-studio-2010, sql-server-ce

I'm getting that error when I try to show table data from a SQL Server CE database. Any idea?

Comment: Reinstall SQL Server Compact 3.5 SP2 or 4.0 desktop runtime

Answer (score 1):

I have that error with visualt studio 2010 after having uninstalled visual studio 2012.
Install visual studio 2012 again and things will work again. It lloks like vs2012 is either removing too many files or not enought dll registry links.